# Отображение элемента с абсолютным позиционирование за пределами v-tab-item в VuetifyJS

Tags: vue.js, vuetify

Пытаюсь сделать стрелки для слайдера за пределами v-tab-item, но как бы я не пытался перебирать разные z-index и делаю разных родителей с position:relative, элемент перекрывается другими элементами.
Пытался простой див вывести вывести за пределы v-tab-item и ситуация та же, он просто чем-то перекрывается. Есть идеи по решению?

Comment: Если в вопросе появится [repro], то и идеи несомненно появятся. Скорее всего, банально неправильные стили (других вероятных причин придумать не получается). У свойства `z-index` есть свои нюансы, например ограничение уровнем слоя родительского элемента - то есть, `z-index` действует "локально", и это надо учитывать, изменяя уровень не только дочернего элемента, но и родительских (если требуется).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня было глупое и банальное решение. Думал, что больший z-index должен выводиться не зависимо от всего остального, а оказалось у родительских элементов был overflow: hidden, который не давал отображаться стрелкам.